# Android - pass values from clicked item on ListView and display them on a new Actvity

Tags: java, android, listview

I am an intern at this company and I have a task assigned to me by my team leader where I need to make an app that displays a list of items that I can add to and edit/delete the items on the list. I am following the requirements given to me on what the app needs to do.

The problem I'm having is that I need to pass values from an item when clicked on a `ListView` which uses a custom adapter, and have them sent to a new activity and displayed on the new activity's `textviews` and `imageview`. I have tried using `putExtras()` methods in the list click method and getting the values using `getExtras()` methods but they didn't work and I've already deleted those codes, so they are no longer there. If you need more of the classes/activities I'm using please let me know. I am using **Android Studio 3.1.4**

**ItemListView.java**

```
public class ItemListView extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDB;

ArrayList<Item> itemList;
ListView listView;

Item item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list_view);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();

    int numRows = data.getCount();
    if(numRows == 0){
        Toast.makeText(ItemListView.this, "There is nothing in the database.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            item = new Item(data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3));
            itemList.add(item);
        }
        Row_ListAdapter adapter = new Row_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, itemList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemListView.this, ViewItemClicked.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**ViewItemClicked.java** 
I want the values displayed onto the layout of this activity when a row is clicked.

```
public class ViewItemClicked extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView image;
    TextView name, desc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_item_clicked);
    }
}
```

Other classes I used:

**Row_ListAdapter.java**

```
public class Row_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private int mViewResourceId;
ImageView image;
TextView name;
TextView description;

public Row_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parents){

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    Item item = items.get(position);

    if(item != null){

        image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconIV);
        name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descTV);

        if(image != null){
            image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        }
        if(name != null){
            name.setText(item.getName());
        }
        if(description != null){
            description.setText(item.getDescription());
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Link to GUI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHfgv.png

Comment: Serialize your item class and pass it to your next activity using `putExtra()` method and fetch it in your next activity using `getSerializableExtra()`

Comment: you need to use putExtra and getExtra methods for transferring data from one acctivity to another, please add the same non working code you deleted and let us check if there is any problem in that

Comment: @VivekMishra i think using `Parceable` is better than `Serializeable`

Comment: @AbdulKawee I once read a post regarding this. Parcelable is faster as compared to Serialization because in it we have to define write and read code. If you do the same for serialization, then it is faster than parcelable.

Comment: @VivekMishra yes exactly serializeable produces alot of junk objects, and as per your logic seriazeable is also fine i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you pass the data, implement your Item Class with Serializable like this:

```
public class Item implements Serializable{
     /*your class code here*/
}
```

Then pass the data in the listView.setOnItemClicklistener like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Item passItem = itemList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemListView.this, ViewItemClicked.class);
            Bundle itemBundle = new Bundle();
            itemBundle.putSerializable("dataItem",passItem)// put the data and define the key
            intent.putExtras(itemBundle)
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and to open the data in the ViewItemClicked.Class

```
public class ViewItemClicked extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView image;
    TextView name, desc;
    Item item;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        item = (Item) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dataItem"); // use the key
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_item_clicked);
        /*now u can use the item data*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your codes worked! I had to switch itemBundle.putSerializable(passItem,"dataItem") to itemBundle.putSerializable("dataItem", passItem), and added the missing codes and it ran

Answer (score 0):

***Try the codes below:***

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemListView.this, ViewItemClicked.class);
            String name = itemList.get(position).getString(1);
            String description = itemList.get(position).getString(2);
            String something_else = itemList.get(position).getString(3);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("something_else", something_else);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

**In your Details Activity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String description = intent.getStringExtra("description");
    String something_else = intent.getStringExtra("something_else");
```

**Now use the strings to show the values in the desired places.
as**

```
edittext.setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

**WHAT FORMAT TYPE OF IMAGE YOUR ARE USING**

Is it Base64 or Bitmap if it is Base64 try this code..

```html
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemListView.this, ViewItemClicked.class);
            String name = list.get(position).getName();
            String description = list.get(position).getDescription();
            String image= list.get(position).getImage();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

In Your Second Activity use this code..

```html
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String description = intent.getStringExtra("description");
    String image = intent.getStringExtra("image");
```

Convert here Base64 to Bitmap..

```
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
 decodedString.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface for listening item click event

```
public class Row_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private int mViewResourceId;
ImageView image;
TextView name;
TextView description;

OnItemListener mListener;

public Row_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parents){

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

    Item item = items.get(position);

    if(item != null){

        image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconIV);
        name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descTV);

        if(image != null){
            image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        }
        if(name != null){
            name.setText(item.getName());
        }
        if(description != null){
            description.setText(item.getDescription());
        }
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onItemClick(v, item);
        }
    })
    return convertView;
}

public void setOnItemListener(OnItemListener listener) {
   mListener = listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
   void onItemClick(View v, Item item);
}

}
```

Then, implement OnItemClickListener in the activity and set it to the adapter:

```
Row_ListAdapter adapter = new Row_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, itemList);
adapter.setOnItemListener("your implement");
```

Comment: interface is actually not much needed in listview. It is more suited for recyclerview. Listview has itemClickListener of its own while recyclerview doesn't.